# How to depict the hydrophobicity for a protein sequence in Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
hydrophobics = "FLIMVPAWG"
sequence = "VLARDNGAF"
```

I Need output as:

```
VLARDNGAF
**    ***
```

Indicating that VLGAF are hydrophobic by printing either '*' or '$' or any symbol exactly below them indicating they are hydrophobic.

```
for aa in sequence:
    if aa in hydrophobics:
        print(aa)
```

I can get the hydrophobic residues, any pointers to get the output as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
hydrophobics = "FLIMVPAWG"
sequence = "VLARDNGAF"


plot = ''
for aa in sequence:
    if aa in hydrophobics:
        plot = plot +  '*'  ### shorter  plot +=  '*'
    else:
        plot = plot +  ' '
        
print(sequence)
print(plot)
```

output:

```
VLARDNGAF
***   ***
```